# Compare two Excel worksheets and copy cell data onto a third sheet when a match is found via Python and Openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

As the title states, I am attempting to match cell data from column 1 of worksheet 0 and compare it to cell data from column 3 of worksheet 1.  If a match occurs, write the matching cell data from worksheet 2's column 1.
I can print the desired data to console but I cannot get it to write the values into cells on worksheet 3.  I have pasted working code but I am unsure how to create the logic for my desired results.  Any assistance is appreciated.

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(r'C:\project.xlsx')
ws1 = wb['Partial']
ws2 = wb['Complete']
ws3 = wb.create_sheet(title='Results')
ws3 = wb.active
for x in ws1['A1:A53']:
    for y in ws2['C1:C1118']:
         if x == y:
            ws3.append(ws2.cell(row = y, column = 1).value)
wb.save('project.xlsx')
```

*modified*

Comment: But does the line like e.g. `ws3.cell(row = 1, column = 1).value = 4` work in general?

Comment: You're reassigning `ws3` just use `ws3 = wb.create_sheet(title='Results')` and use openpyxl's methods for accessing rows rather than your own counter.

Comment: Hi @CharlieClark.  I've made some changes to my code based on your feedback but I am still not achieving my desired results.  Could you clarify which methods I would use to iterate through these cells and paste the desired data to a cell?

`import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(r'C:\project.xlsx')
ws1 = wb['Partial']
ws2 = wb['Complete']
ws3 = wb.create_sheet(title='Results')
ws3 = wb.active
for x in ws1['A1:A53']:
    for y in ws2['C1:C1118']:
         if ws1['A1:A53'] == ws2['C1:C1118']:
            ws3.append(ws2.cell(row = y, column = 1).value)
wb.save('project.xlsx')`

Comment: Please edit the code in the question, it's unreadable here. The documentation explains how to loop programmatically over cells.

Comment: @CharlieClark I've made the changes to my original code.  Sorry for the mess.  I read the documentation and perhaps iter_rows with no range defined would give me the results I desire.